# How to prove that if $x,y,z$ are random variables in $\Bbb{Z}_{257}$, then (x+y+z) is random.

Tags: probability, modular-arithmetic, random-variables

I would like to prove or disprove that if $x,y,z$ are three random variables in $\Bbb{Z}_{257}$, then (x+y+z) is random in $\Bbb{Z}_{257}$.
**Added:** 
Suppose $z,y,z$ are uniformly distributed in $\Bbb{Z}_{257}$, then $Pr(x)=\dfrac{1}{257}=Pr(y)=Pr(z)$. We have to calculate $Pr(x+y+z)=?$

Comment: I think it could help to look at it's joint probability function entropy. They could all be individually random, but for example if $y=k-x-z$ for some $k$ then the sum won't be very random.

Comment: You probably mean for $x$, $y$, and $z$ to be mutually independent. Suggestion 1: try it for $n=4$ or some other small number where you can explicitly look at the entire sample space. Suggestion 2: First show that $x+y$ is uniformly distributed, then that same argument applied to $(x+y)$ and $z$ ...